# ul tag set responsive not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a responsive ul tag, I want two rows of two columns on computer screen and mobile view one columns and four rows. i tried lot of examples but they didnt help me. im new at html and css

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50%;
    }
  @media screen and (min-width: 20em) {
    li {
      width: 33.33333%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">text1 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">text2 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">text3 </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">text4 </a></li>
           </ul>                       
  </div>
```

so i want this result on computer screen

```
text1      text2
text3      text4
```

and mobile view

```
text1
text2 
text3
text4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<li<a href="#">text2 </a></li>` so please correct your code and change it `<li><a href="#">text2 </a></li>`

**Here is jsfiddle link**

**[update code](https://jsfiddle.net/v8o3j7wf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the 'twitter-bootstrap' tag, I assume you can use/are using bootstrap.
So you can simply use the following code:

```
<div class="row">
     <ul>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text1 </a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text2 </a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text3 </a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text4 </a></li>
     </ul>                       
</div>
```

```html
<div class="row">
         <ul>
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text1 </a></li>
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text2 </a></li>
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text3 </a></li>
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><a href="#">text4 </a></li>
         </ul>                       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your second `li` syntax.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) {
  li {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">text1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text2 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text3 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text4 </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```